# Android Espresso testcases are faling in jenkins

Tags: android, junit4, android-espresso

I've recently started writing espresso testcases. I've written few testcases for my application and the problem im facing is... I need to put one Sleep at the first testcase of each testsuite though Espresso is known for UI Thread Synchronization. Putting one sleep is okay for me(can live with that)... but the main problem is, When i run testcases from my local android studio, all the testcases are executing successfully. But when i run the same testcases from my local/server jenkins almost 99% of the testcases are failing. Most of the time im getting AppNotIdleException. I've disabled the animations even in jenkins emulators also. Unable to figure out the rootcause. Guys please help.

Comment: Did you get any such kind of issue in your local machine?

Comment: One more question, Will your app keep showing any progress indicator for more than 45 sec?

Comment: I wont get any issues in local machine all are working fine locally....and im mocking the service responses...so no progress indicator is shown for such long duration.

Comment: Did you have any more info of the exception?

Comment: I guess AppNotIdleException is only info i have.

Comment: What is the command you are using to run the test? Are you trying with the same command in local?

Comment: Yeah of course ....i'm using the same command(_**connectedActiveDebugAndroidTest**_) in both local & jenkins...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138942/discussion-between-tca-and-naresh-gunda).

Comment: right now im in office...and chat is blocked. :(, will add a comment once i reach home. If you are intrested will sure continue.

Comment: Classic Friday night issue.. Just ping here...  we can talk  :)